# Finding windspeed gave me negative time value

Tags: aircraft

This is a homework question, I will make it as concise as possible:

> A 1-way plane trip is 2800km and the plane's airspeed is 790km/h. The plane flies with the wind on the way there, and against it on the way back. It took 1 hour longer going from point B to A (returning flight) than to go from A to B (to the destination). What's the windspeed?

I started assigning variables:

$r_{g1}={}$groundspeed on the way there

$r_{g2}={}$groundspeed on the way back (against wind)

$r_a={}$airspeed

$t_1={}$time in hours it takes to get *there* AND
$t_2={}$time in hours it takes to get *back*

$w={}$windspeed

Next I set up equations relating these variables:

$$r_{g1}=r_{a}+w$$
$$r_{g1}=\frac{2800}{t_1}$$
$$r_{g2}=r_{a}-w$$
and since $$t_2=t_1+1$$ this means
$$r_{g2}=\frac{2800}{t_1+1}$$

Next we have:
$$\frac{2800}{t_1}=r_a+w$$
$$\frac{2800}{t_1+1}=r_a-w$$

Then solve for w in both equations:
$$w=\frac{2800}{t_1}-r_a$$
$$w=\frac{-2800}{t_1+1}+r_a$$
Then I set them equal and solved for $t_1$ to back-substitute:
$$\frac{2800}{t_1}-r_a=\frac{-2800}{t_1+1}+r_a$$
$$\frac{2800}{t_1}=\frac{-2800}{t_1+1}$$
$$2800({t_1+1})=-2800{t_1}$$
$$({t_1+1})=-{t_1}$$
$$2t_1=-1$$
This gives me $t=-0.5$ hours which makes no sense. Where did I go wrong?
Thanks so much.

Comment: The algebra in this problem results in a quadratic form.  This leads to 2 roots, one positive and one negative.  You solved for the negative root.

Comment: @DavidWhite I’m not sure I understand what you’re saying. Where’s the quadratic?

Comment: Cotton Headed Ninnymuggins, I'll post a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, it was intended as a hint to get the OP headed in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$
$$\frac{2800}{t_1}-r_a=\frac{-2800}{t_1+1}+r_a$$
$$\xcancel{\frac{2800}{t_1}=\frac{-2800}{t_1+1}}$$
Did you add $r_a$ to both sides or subtract $r_a$ from both sides? Look closely.

Comment: That’s it right there. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Given that $v$ equals the speed of the wind, an equation that represents the time of travel of the airplane for the forward and return trips, in terms of velocities and distances, is:

$$\frac{2800}{790-v}=\frac{2800}{790+v}+1$$ ${}$

This equation becomes quadratic in $v$, requiring the quadratic equation to solve, resulting in two roots.  One root is negative and one root is positive.

Comment: So which equation that I created was wrong? I’m assuming I did all the math correctly right?